# Outlook Shared Folders

Tags: outlook, inbox

On Thursday, we started getting an error when opening the Salesforce sidebar in Outlook Shared Folders. The error says

> Sorry to interrupt. This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [PromiseRejection: [object Object]]
> Something happened when we tried to connect to the Exchange server. View more details.

The view more details link says "Error Code: " (just blank error code).

Anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Outlook Integration unable to access Shared folders with the following error "Hmm. The email server is unavailable. Please try again later."](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001oFj5QAE) (IN REVIEW - Last Updated 3 days ago)

Summary

Outlook integration is unable to resolve shared folder access and presents the following error: "Hmm. The email server is unavailable. Please try again later." Microsoft has removed the capability of accessing shared folders via EWS causing this feature to no longer work.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access?tabs=windows#rest-and-ews

Repro

Attempt to add an email or event from a shared folder using Outlook integration

Workaround

None

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.